# How can I audit performance while screen is asleep to troubleshoot audio issues?

Tags: windows-8.1, audio, performance

I am having issues with my audio being choppy when my laptop's screen goes to sleep.

Specifically, I want a log of the following:

- Applications' resource usage
- Any resource spikes

Any recommendations?

Comment: [Resource Monitor](http://www.maketecheasier.com/track-applications-resource-usage-in-windows-7) and [Process Monitor](http://www.maketecheasier.com/monitor-application-in-windows7).

Comment: @Karan ProcMon is exactly what I needed. Please submit as answer. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to monitor and log a whole host of information about a process, including capturing various process details, full thread stacks for each operation, real-time file system/Registry/process & thread activity, CPU/RAM usage and much more.

[image: 1]